# if/else statement doesn't work after an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide, show, show-hide

I'm currently trying to implement a bit of AJAX in my code for a `like` button.
I'm displaying the `Like` and `Dislike` button on the screen. I make an AJAX request to check my database, and depending the result. One of the buttons should hide.

Here my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function check(){
        var urliditem = document.location.href;
        var splitted = urliditem.split('item=');
        var id = splitted[1];

        $.post(
            "ajax/likes.php",
            { id: id },
            function(check){
                alert(check);
                if (check == 1){
                    //show the Like button
                    $("#dislike").hide();
                }
                else if (check == 0){
                    //show the Dislike button
                    $("#like").hide();
                }
                else{
                    alert('An error has occured');
                }
            }
        );  
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#test").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            check();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I check if I got a result from my AJAX request, but the if/else statements seem to not work after the call. I don't understand why. It's maybe the show()/hide() functions that don't work.

Any idea ? Is my script correct ?

### Buttons

```
<?php
    echo '<div id="dislike" class="likes">'.$donneeitem['likes'].' ♥</div><a class="btn-primary btn pull-right" href="index.php?page=action&action=unlikeitem&id='.$_GET['item'].'">Unlike</a>';
    echo '<div id="like" class="likes">'.$donneeitem['likes'].' ♥</div><a class="btn-primary btn pull-right" href="index.php?page=action&action=likeitem&id='.$_GET['item'].'">Like</a>';
?>
```

### ajax/likes.php

```
    $check = db_query('SELECT * FROM likes_item WHERE user_id = ? AND item_id = ?', array($_SESSION['mc']['id'], $item_id))->fetchColumn();
    if ($check>0) {
        echo 0; //To show the Dislike button
    }
    else {
        echo 1; //To show the Like button
    }
```

Comment: What is the returned value of `check`?

Comment: Well, I have the same result with the console.log(check). Where do you see that redundant quotation ?  The returned value of check is 0 or 1

Comment: I have a 0, as it was expected

Comment: Ok, let's go the other way around: do you have an alert (with 'An error...') shown? What happens when you add `console.log($('#like'))` into `if (check == 0)` branch?

Comment: `check` is probably a string and not an integer. Try `console.log(typeof check, check == 1, check == "1")` and then check your console for results. Altho with only `==`, it shouldn't matter, but it will help us know exactly your return which is better to evaluate

Comment: No, this alert is not shown. And I've got 111 when I add console.log(111) into if (check === 0) branch

Comment: I have string false false

Comment: Sigh... do you understand now that you were wrong all the time? It has nothing to do with `if/else`, as the correct branch is reached... Now it's time to show us the HTML, I suppose; how these `#like` and `#unlike` buttons are created.

Comment: Please add this to the question itself.

Comment: `string false false` means I was right about the string, and your if|else isn't working because `check` is not `1` nor is it `"1"`. So what are you returning from `ajax/likes.php`? I'll look back through comments as I'm sure this has been addressed, but your return is wrong for that `if|else`

Comment: Try checking what you're returning with `console.log(check)` and makes sure it's what you're `echo`ing in `ajax/likes.php`. Remember, `ajax/likes.php` needs to end with an echo statement of what you want returned, such as `echo($someVariableToEvaluate ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: It's eactly what I have in ajax/likes.php

Comment: Here is what I have in likes.php: `$check = db_query('SELECT * FROM likes_item WHERE user_id = ? AND item_id = ?', array($_SESSION['mc']['id'], $item_id))->fetchColumn();

 if ($check>0)
  {
   echo 0; //To show the Dislike button
  }
 
 else 
  {
   echo 1; //To show the Like button
  }`

Comment: Well your if statement is `if (check == 1)` but you said `console.log(typeof check, check == 1, check == "1")` returned `string false false` which means you ARE NOT echoing a `1` or `0`

Comment: It's a red herring, seriously. We've already confirmed that `if (check == 0)` branch is assessed, and that the element is in place (at least if the OP did all like he was told). Now the only question is whether or not `hide()` actually works here.

Comment: Then why have I 1 or 0 when I do a consol.log(check) ?

Comment: @raina77ow ah i c, well that earlier return of `string false false` through me down a rabbit hole, but I'll let you continue with this. I gota get back to work. lol

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your script as below, this will hide the button you don't want, and show the respective buttons, the code you wrote seems just to hide the button and not show it.

```
function(check){
            alert(check);
            if (check == 1){
                //show the Like button
                $("#dislike").hide();
                $("#like").show();
            }
            else if (check == 0){
                //show the Dislike button
                $("#like").hide();
                $("#dislike").show();
            }
                else{
                    alert('An error has occured');
                }
            }
```